# CQ5 how does the sling resolver find an asset in the repository?

Tags: osgi, aem, sling, dam

I am trying to get the last modified time for a resource from the JCR based upon the sling address provided within the provided tag link.

For example, if we have a cq page, with a parsys containing an image tag, the src tag provides /content/mysite/subdir/page/_jcr_content/section/par/image.img.jpg/1377167279557.jpg

What I am trying to get, is the image resource at /content/dam/geometrixx-media/articles/mountain-bike.jpg so that I can examine the metadata for the last modified time.

I would also like to do the same for scripts etc, so I am looking for the way that CQ5 does this internally, as when you hit the link /content/mysite/subdir/page/_jcr_content/section/par/image.img.jpg/1377167279557.jpg you get the right asset rendering out.

I have tried Resource res = resResolver.resolve(httpServletRequest, originalValue); however, I get sling:nonexisting as a result, although if I enter localhost:4502/content/mysite/subdir/page/_jcr_content/section/par/image.img.jpg/1377167279557.jpg the resource still shows up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `http://localhost:4502/system/console/requests`
2. Choose "clear"
3. Browse to the image in a different tab
4. Go back to Recent requests in Felix & refresh the page.
5. You'll see a link related to the image — click on this & it will tell you how Sling resolved the file, including any scripts used to render it out.

More info on the [**Sling site here**](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/monitoring-requests.html).